# Invalid method Yoast_MetaRobots_Block_Catalog_Product_View:

Tags: magento-1.7

Getting this error on Magento 1.7 when attempting to view a product page for any product on the site. We have recompiled, cleared all cache and reindexed the site with no solution.

> Invalid method
>   Yoast_MetaRobots_Block_Catalog_Product_View::addAttribute(Array (
>       [0] => warranty ) )
>
> Trace:
>   0 [internal function]: Varien_Object->__call('addAttribute', Array)
>   1 [internal function]: Yoast_MetaRobots_Block_Catalog_Product_View->addAttribute('warranty')
>
> 2 /home/omegajui/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(348):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
>
> 3 /home/omegajui/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(214):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateAction(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
>
> 4 /home/omegajui/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
>
> 5 /home/omegajui/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
>
> 6 /home/omegajui/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(113):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
>
> 7 /home/omegajui/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52):
>   Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController),
>   'no-route')
>
> 8/home/omegajui/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(75):
>   Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController),
>   'no-route')
>
> 9 /home/omegajui/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419):
>   Mage_Cms_IndexController->noRouteAction()
>
> 10/home/omegajui/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('noRoute')
>
> 11 /home/omegajui/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>
> 12 /home/omegajui/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>
> 13 /home/omegajui/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>
> 14 /home/omegajui/public_html/index.php(86): Mage::run('', 'store')
>
> 15 {main}